# What's the root cause of the this crash in iOS?

Tags: ios, dns, crash, webkit

After I use flurry to collect the crash reports in my app, I found a lot of crash like this:

```
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3340d6ba _objc_retain + 9
1   libsystem_network.dylib             0x33a8a32b <redacted> + 1402
2   libsystem_dnssd.dylib               0x33a07a81 <redacted> + 308
3   libsystem_dnssd.dylib               0x33a065bb _DNSServiceProcessResult + 550
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x33964253 <redacted> + 626
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x339553f9 <redacted> + 212
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3395b48f <redacted> + 502
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3395609d <redacted> + 84
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3395cba1 <redacted> + 320
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x3395dcd7 <redacted> + 94
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x33ab4e31 __pthread_wqthread + 668
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x33ab4b84 _start_wqthread + 8
```

and another crash:

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x2dde782e _CFArrayGetCount + 5
1   WebCore                             0x3610dddd -[WAKView subviews] + 36
2   WebCore                             0x3610dd99 -[WAKView viewWillDraw] + 20
3   WebCore                             0x3610dc85 <redacted> + 64
4   QuartzCore                          0x30348e3b <redacted> + 350
5   QuartzCore                          0x30348ccd <redacted> + 16
6   QuartzCore                          0x303486df <redacted> + 230
7   QuartzCore                          0x303484ef <redacted> + 314
8   UIKit                               0x306c842b <redacted> + 126
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2de7f2a5 <redacted> + 20
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2de7cc49 <redacted> + 284
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2de7cf8b <redacted> + 730
12  CoreFoundation                      0x2dde7f4f _CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
13  CoreFoundation                      0x2dde7d33 _CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
14  GraphicsServices                    0x32d40663 _GSEventRunModal + 138
15  UIKit                               0x3073316d _UIApplicationMain + 1136
```

What's the root cause for them? I had google a lot about them, but I can't found any useful about them.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Don't use Stack Snippets for code that is not in HTML, JavaScript, or CSS.  A Stack Snippet is used to create runnable code snippets in HTML/JavaScript/CSS.  Use a Code Sample (which has a {} icon) instead.

Comment: No error message,just crash.

Comment: Maybe you need to upload your zipped dSym folder to Flurry to desymbolicate the stack trace if you haven't already done so. Hopefully that will show some more useful error message. Sometimes even after desymbolicating, the crash error still isn't very useful.

Comment: Thank you, I had do it, but the crash stack seems not from the app's code, it's from the webkit and  DNSService.

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm seeing similar two crashes with an enterprise Cordova iPad app.

Comment: Any resolutions on this?